# Perfomances, slow load of query with multiples left join

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm struggling a lot with a big doctrine query, there is 17000 contacts in the database and near 1 millions rows for statistics and orders.

As you can see there is a lot of calculated values, i really need theses values to performs filtering.

At first i tried to do that query with DQL but it's just as bad in term of performances, the query takes more than 15 or 30 seconds..

The goal is to have the 17000 rows for each contacts with their calculated values.

Is anyone can give me some advices, i'm sure i'm not the only one who needs to do that kind of queries!

Thanks in advance :)

This is the doctrine query builder

```
 $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('contact');

    $qb->select("contact.id");
    $qb->addSelect("contact.source");
    $qb->addSelect("contact.updatedAt");
    $qb->addSelect("contact.createdAt");

    // orders
    $qb->addSelect("COUNT(distinct shop_order.id) AS totalOrders");
    $qb->addSelect("SUM(distinct shop_order.price) AS totalSpentOrders");
    $qb->addSelect("AVG(distinct shop_order.price) AS averageCart");
    $qb->addSelect("MAX(shop_order.createdAt) AS lastOrderDatedAt");
    $qb->addSelect("MIN(shop_order.createdAt) AS firstOrderDatedAt");
    $qb->addSelect("last_shop_order.price AS totalSpentLastOrder");

    // orders statuses
    $qb->addSelect("COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN shop_order.status = " . Order::STATUS_WAITING . " THEN shop_order.id ELSE :empty END)) AS totalOrdersWaitingOrError");
    $qb->addSelect("COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN shop_order.status = " . Order::STATUS_PAID . " THEN shop_order.id ELSE :empty END)) AS totalOrdersPaid");
    $qb->addSelect("COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN shop_order.status = " . Order::STATUS_DELIVERED . " THEN shop_order.id ELSE :empty END)) AS totalOrdersDelivered");
    $qb->addSelect("COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN shop_order.status = " . Order::STATUS_PAYMENT_ERROR . " THEN shop_order.id ELSE :empty END)) AS totalOrdersPaymentError");
    $qb->addSelect("COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN shop_order.status = " . Order::STATUS_SHIPPED . " THEN shop_order.id ELSE :empty END)) AS totalOrdersShipped");
    $qb->addSelect("COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN shop_order.status = " . Order::STATUS_ABORTED . " THEN shop_order.id ELSE :empty END)) AS totalOrdersAborted");

    $qb->leftJoin("contact.orders", "shop_order", Join::WITH, "shop_order.isValid = 1 AND shop_order.contact = contact");
    $qb->leftJoin("contact.orders", "last_shop_order", Join::WITH, "last_shop_order = FIRST(SELECT lso FROM App:Order lso WHERE lso.isValid = 1 AND lso.contact = contact ORDER BY lso.createdAt DESC)");

    // order cart
    $qb->leftJoin("shop_order.cart", "cart");
    $qb->leftJoin("cart.productCarts", "product_carts");
    $qb->leftJoin("product_carts.product", "product");

    // abandonned carts
    $qb->addSelect("COUNT(distinct abandonned_cart.id) AS totalAbandonnedCarts");
    $qb->addSelect("SUM(distinct abandonned_product.price) AS totalAmountAbandonnedCarts");

    $qb->leftJoin("contact.carts", "abandonned_cart");
    $qb->leftJoin("abandonned_cart.shopOrder", "abandonned_shop_order");
    $qb->leftJoin("abandonned_cart.productCarts", "abandonned_product_cart");
    $qb->leftJoin("abandonned_product_cart.product", "abandonned_product");
    $qb->andWhere("abandonned_shop_order.id IS NULL");

    $qb->addSelect("SUM(distinct last_abandonned_cart.amount) AS totalAmountLastAbandonnedCart");

    $qb->leftJoin("contact.carts", "last_abandonned_cart", Join::WITH, "last_abandonned_cart = FIRST(SELECT lac FROM App:Cart lac LEFT JOIN lac.shopOrder lacso WHERE lacso IS NULL AND lac.contact = contact ORDER BY lac.createdAt DESC)");
    $qb->leftJoin("last_abandonned_cart.productCarts", "last_abandonned_product_cart");
    $qb->leftJoin("last_abandonned_product_cart.product", "last_abandonned_product");

    // behavior
    $qb->addSelect("COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN contact_stat.type = " . ContactStat::TYPE_EMAIL_SENT . " THEN contact_stat.id ELSE :empty END)) AS totalEmailSent");
    $qb->addSelect("COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN contact_stat.type = " . ContactStat::TYPE_EMAIL_CLICKED . " THEN contact_stat.id ELSE :empty END)) AS totalEmailClicked");
    $qb->addSelect("COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN contact_stat.type = " . ContactStat::TYPE_EMAIL_OPENED . " THEN contact_stat.id ELSE :empty END)) AS totalEmailOpened");
    $qb->addSelect("(COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN contact_stat.type = " . ContactStat::TYPE_EMAIL_CLICKED . " THEN contact_stat.id ELSE :empty END)) / COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN contact_stat.type = " . ContactStat::TYPE_EMAIL_SENT . " THEN contact_stat.id ELSE :empty END))) * 100 AS emailClickedRate");
    $qb->addSelect("(COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN contact_stat.type = " . ContactStat::TYPE_EMAIL_OPENED . " THEN contact_stat.id ELSE :empty END)) / COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN contact_stat.type = " . ContactStat::TYPE_EMAIL_SENT . " THEN contact_stat.id ELSE :empty END))) * 100  AS emailOpenedRate");
    $qb->leftJoin("contact.contactStats", "contact_stat");

    // other contact informations
    $qb->leftJoin("contact.address", "address");
    $qb->leftJoin("contact.contactOperations", "contact_operation");
    $qb->leftJoin("contact_operation.operation", "operation");
    $qb->leftJoin("contact.accountTypes", "account_type");
    $qb->leftJoin("contact.medicalInformation", "medical_information");

    $qb->setParameter("empty", null);

    $qb->orderBy("contact.updatedAt", "DESC");
    $qb->groupBy("contact.id");
```

I tried to removed some of the joins and the calculated values this is the SQL query :

```
SELECT 
c0_.id AS id_0, 
c0_.email AS email_1, 
c0_.first_name AS first_name_2, 
c0_.last_name AS last_name_3, 
c0_.type AS type_4, 
c0_.updated_at AS updated_at_5, 
c0_.source AS source_6, 
c0_.created_at AS created_at_7, 
a1_.postcode AS postcode_8, 
a1_.country AS country_9, 
m2_.skin_type AS skin_type_10, 
c0_.is_optin_sms AS is_optin_sms_11 
FROM 
contact c0_ 
LEFT JOIN address a1_ ON c0_.address_id = a1_.id 
LEFT JOIN medical_information m2_ ON c0_.id = m2_.contact_id 
LEFT JOIN contact_operation c3_ ON c0_.id = c3_.contact_id 
LEFT JOIN operation o4_ ON c3_.operation_id = o4_.id 
LEFT JOIN account_type_contact a6_ ON c0_.id = a6_.contact_id 
LEFT JOIN account_type a5_ ON a5_.id = a6_.account_type_id 
LEFT JOIN contact_stat c7_ ON c0_.id = c7_.contact_id 
LEFT JOIN shop_order s8_ ON c0_.id = s8_.contact_id 
AND (
s8_.is_valid = 1 
AND s8_.contact_id = c0_.id
) 
LEFT JOIN shop_order s9_ ON c0_.id = s9_.contact_id 
AND (
s9_.id = (
  SELECT 
    s10_.id 
  FROM 
    shop_order s10_ 
  WHERE 
    s10_.is_valid = 1 
    AND s10_.contact_id = c0_.id 
  ORDER BY 
    s10_.created_at DESC 
  LIMIT 
    1
)
) LEFT JOIN cart c11_ ON s8_.cart_id = c11_.id 
LEFT JOIN product_cart p12_ ON c11_.id = p12_.cart_id 
LEFT JOIN product p13_ ON p12_.product_id = p13_.id 
LEFT JOIN cart c14_ ON c0_.id = c14_.contact_id 
LEFT JOIN shop_order s15_ ON c14_.id = s15_.cart_id 
AND (
s15_.id IS NULL 
AND s15_.contact_id = c0_.id
) 
GROUP BY 
c0_.id 
ORDER BY 
c0_.updated_at DESC
```

The query take more than 8 seconds..

There is the Explain of the query

[image]

---

Comment: What is the "pure" SQL that you run? I'm talking about doing it directly from the mysql CLI?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but the SQL query i run is the one i pasted.

Answer (score 0):

- Please don't use `LEFT` unless you are expecting there to be no row in the 'right' table.  Unnecessary use of `LEFT` confuses the user and the reader.
- Don't include tables that you don't need.  (Eg, c7_)  The Optimizer assumes you need every table given, so it fails to throw out useless joins.
- This seems to be an "explode-implode" query.  First the query gathers lots of data from multiple tables, then in consolidates the data via a `GROUP BY`.  This is often inefficient and avoidable.  The technique is to first write a query that gets c0_.id with as few joins as possible.  The may eliminate the need for the `GROUP BY`.  Then apply the joins.  This is likely to include a `JOIN` back to `contacts` to get the other columns of that table.

This smells like a query that was generated by some third-party sofware?  I hope you can work around it.